# SELECT a decimal if NULL show N/A else show USD Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullif

I have a field called Amount type of Decimal(12,2).

Amount, can accept NULL and decimal value example 100.00.

```
SELECT
NULLIF(Amount, 'N/A') AS Amount
FROM PRODUCTS;
```

This cause:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I want to SELECT a decimal 
if NULL show 'N/A' 
else show 'USD Amount'

Hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: In database speak its not a field, its a column.

Comment: This is something for your presentation layer *not* the SQL layer. Also `NULLIF(Amount, 'N/A')` makes no sense here; a `decimal` can *never* have the value `'N/A'` you would want `ISNULL` if you had to do this. `NULLIF` returns `NULL` *if*` the first parameter is equal to the second, not returns the second parameter if the first is `NULL`.

Comment: `NULLIF` requires both arguments to be the same datatype, so convert you number to a varchar if you want to `nullif` it with "N/A".

Comment: Note that replacing `NULLIF` with `ISNULL` will generate the same error; `ISNULL` will implicitly cast the second parameter to the datatype of the first (and, again, `'N/A'` is is not a valid `decimal` value). This is why I explicitly stated you should be doing this in your presentation layer (as casting numerical data to a string based data type is generally a very poor idea).

Comment: It for listing (display data) use only.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Amount to a varchar then apply isnull

`SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Amount),'N/A') as Amount FROM PRODUCTS;`

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer:

```
SELECT IIF(Amount IS NULL, 'N/A', 'USD' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),Amount)) as Amount FROM PRODUCTS;
```

Reference link : [SQL Function IIF](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

Thanks.